# Which countries are not recognized by or don't recognize France

Tags: france, countries

After some research, I haven't found a precise list of countries which don't recognize France as a country and vice-versa (list of countries which are not recognized by France).

I think **if such list exist** it will not be long but I keep asking to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not sure about the first one but anyway I need a precise list

Comment: that wasn't an answer, it is a comment, this is a feature in SE when you have no answer but still want to write something ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a list

Comment: @GayotFow are lists intrinsically off topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about international recognition, not travel.

Comment: @phoog eliciting list-style answers, suggestions or recommendations on a topic or place (unless VERY specific criteria is listed)

Comment: some useful info on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_France)

Comment: Taiwan [the Republic of China] is probably the most notable case, although in practise they have informal relations. The People's Republic will only entertain diplomatic relations with those who formally reject Taiwan's statehood.

Comment: I think the "list of countries that don't recognize France as a country" would be a very short list. Quite possibly an *empty* list.

Comment: Both lists may be empty: France recognize all countries: It just uses a specific definition of _country_ (as all other countries do).

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: France recognized the State of Palestine in December 2014.

Answer (score 2):

That list is impossible to create

What you are asking for is an X subset of the set of countries (I will use C to refer to it) where each member of X is not recognized by France (or doesn't recognize France but that's unlikely to be true for any country). The problem here is that C is not well defined. What do you do with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_North_Sudan for example? As C is a finite set it can be provided obviously by listing its members however until such a list is provided and agreed upon it is quite obvious X can not be provided.